# How to put Null value in a SQL sever via php code

Tags: php, sql-server

I have the following code, which will get values from these 9 variables and insert them in to a table. However, I don't know how to insert `NULL` value in to my table. As shown in line 10, if I try to use the keyword `NULL`, it consider as a string.

```
        $WorkOrder = $_POST['WorkOrder'];
        $Originated = $_POST['Originated'];
        $CustID = $_POST['CustID'];
        $Customer = $_POST['Customer'];
        $Contact = $_POST['Contact'];
        $Completed = $_POST['Completed'];
        $AccountNum = $_POST['AccountNum'];
        $Description = $_POST['Description'];
        $Status = $_POST['Status'];
        $Status = "NULL"; //Testing with NULL

        $insertquery = "INSERT INTO ElectronicShop(WorkOrder, Originated, CustID, Customer, Contact, Completed, AccountNum, Description, Status) 
                       VALUES ('$WorkOrder','$Originated','$CustID','$Customer','$Contact','$Completed','$AccountNum','$Description','$Status')";
        $data = sqlsrv_query($connectString, $insertquery) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL), true));
```

I will be getting values for these 9 variables via text boxes in a webpage. So, I can't manually enter `NULL` in my query.

Comment: `NULL` should be without quotes. It's not a string. Instead of `'$Status'` use `$Status`.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments and answers. Using `$Status` instead of the `'Status'` will output an error. If i use `$Status = null` instead of what I have above, it's still going to record the result as an empty string and doesn't insert the value `NULL` in my table.

Comment: Now I see my error, use Trickzter answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$insertquery = "INSERT INTO ElectronicShop(WorkOrder, Originated, CustID, Customer,  Contact, Completed, AccountNum, Description, Status) VALUES ('$WorkOrder','$Originated','$CustID','$Customer','$Contact','$Completed','$AccountNum','$Description','$Status')";
```

Use:

```
$insertquery = "INSERT INTO ElectronicShop(WorkOrder, Originated, CustID, Customer, Contact, Completed, AccountNum, Description, Status) VALUES
('$WorkOrder','$Originated','$CustID','$Customer','$Contact','$Completed','$AccountNum','$Description', NULL)";
```

You don't need to specify a variable for it, just write "NULL" without string marking signs (') into your query.

Greetz

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Using `NULL` like this in the query will work. however I can't manually use this in a query since I am getting these values from a variable. for example, `$_POST['Status'];` will refer to the value I obtain from a user when he/she enter a value in to a text box in a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the qoutes "":

> $Status = "NULL";

Use:

> $Status = null;

Answer (score 0):

If you have not default value for Status column another than NULL, simply do not use this column in the columns list of insert statement.